# connectionString in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I am stuck. I have spent nearly a day to solve but to no avail.

PROBLEM: Connecting to production database using entity framework.

I connect fine on development.

```
<add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MONDO;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="MONDOEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MONDO;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Moving to production, I used (from the production web.config file) the existing "DefaultConnectionString" parameters (ID and Password) to edit the MONDOEntities connectionString. (can I do this?) Also, I expanded the metadata in MONDOEntities to include .csdl, .ssdl, .msl and I prefixed it with (guessing, again, can I do this?) MONDO. Bold parts are changes from dev web.config to production web.config. *Note, the connectionStrings below were not created by Visual Studio, I just changed some info myself to try and make it work on the production side.

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=MPOC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Mondo;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxx;" name="DefaultConnectionString" />

<add name="MONDOEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MONDO.csdl|res://*/MONDO.ssdl|res://*/MONDO.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MPOC\SQLEXPRESS;persist security info=True;Database=Mondo;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=Tru e;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The error message I get is:
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

```
Line 62: /// Initializes a new MONDOEntities object using the connection string found      in the 'MONDOEntities' section of the application configuration file.
Line 63: /// </summary>
Line 64: public MONDOEntities() :
```

QUESTION: Can I simply modify the connectionStrings manually or does it need to run through a compilation process? It is a website project so it compiles, on the fly, the first time after I upload to production. It does not get precompiled on my local dev computer. I guess, bottom line, how do I set up a proper connectionString for an entity connection for a database in production?

---

I'm on a project where I need to learn an existing website. I'm making my first bug fix and having learned ado.net, I created an entity data model and made some code changes. Everything works smooth in development.

I move the files to production and then I get this error:

```
"The specified default EntityContainer name 'MONDOEntities' could not be found in the mapping and metadata information.
Parameter name: defaultContainerName"
```

I googled this error message and based on some findings, I expanded my "metadata" shown below. This was more of a shot in dark for me:

ORIGINAL (auto generated in web.config when I created the entity data model):

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*
```

NEW (I edited/added this):

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/MONDO.csdl|res://*/MONDO.ssdl|res://*/MONDO.msl;
```

This seemed to get past the first error and I get to a new error message (as posted in OP):

```
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Line 62: /// Initializes a new MONDOEntities object using the connection string found     in the 'MONDOEntities' section of the application configuration file.
Line 63: /// </summary>
Line 64: public MONDOEntities() :
```

I think that there is a problem with my metadata information. However, given that the original, auto generated connectString only contains "metadata=res://*", I really don't know how to go about correcting this. Actually, I'm not even super sure that this is the root of the problem.

Bottom line, my entity model works smooth in dev but isn't connecting in production. Any thoughts are appreciated ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string has nothing to do with compilation, as long as you didn't define some transformation to be performed on it or you have some custom hooks that operate on it.
So yeah, you can modify it by hand.

You probably got those metadata wrong, try and play with them (EG removing the prefix).

Also are you absolutely sure that, in your production environment, the right connectionString is being loaded and used by the MONDOEntities?

Comment: Here's my research so far: oops, I'll post below, not here in comment section ... no formatting here ... ;-x